# Como retornar valor inteiro em pthread?

Tags: c, thread

Como retornar um valor inteiro e conseguir mostrar com printf usando pthread ? Segue um exemplo do problema :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>   


void *somar(void *arg);
int main() {
    int res;
    pthread_t a_thread;
    void *thread_result;
    int n1=2;
    res = pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, somar,&n1);
    if (res != 0 ) {
        perror("Erro\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    res = pthread_join(a_thread, &thread_result);
    if (res != 0) {
        perror("Join falhou");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int *aux1;
    aux1=malloc(sizeof(int));
    aux1=(int*)thread_result;
    int aux2 = *aux1;
    printf(" O valor da soma foi %d\n",aux2);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *somar(void *arg) {
    int *i;
    i = malloc(sizeof(int));
     i= (int*)arg;
    int soma=0;
    for(int j=1;j<=*i;j++){
        soma = soma +*i;
    }
    printf("Soma foi %d\n",soma);
    pthread_exit(&soma);
}
```

Mas aparentemente, ai só esta retornando o endereço da memoria da variável e não o valor dela propriamente dito.

Na função é printado o valor esperado mas na main não aparece corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está retornando o endereço de uma variável local. E isso é um problema com ou sem threads.
Já que você está alocando um memória para seu `i` (e não desalocando, o que é outro problema), aproveite para usá-lo como portador do resultado:

```
//...
printf("Soma foi %d\n",soma);
*i = soma;
pthread_exit(i);
```

Na função `main`, `thread_result` irá apontar para o valor alocado dentro da thread. Depois de lê-lo você deve liberar a memória com:

```
free(thread_result);
```

A outra alocação de memória lá é desnecessária.

Comment: Perfeito, deu certo.  Obrigado.